# Graphs: Topological ordering, explanation required

Tags: graph

Can someone explain "Topological Ordering" of `DAGs` in context of the following graphs?[image]

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting If this isn't enough - ask a more focused question.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering `(1,2,4,3)` is a correct ordering for diagram 1, but not for diagram 2 since the edge `(3,4)` in diagram 2 contradicts the ordering.

Comment: So is it all about "Graphical representation"? I can write the second one as (1,2,3,4)

Comment: That would be an valid/correct/legal ordering for diagram 2 (not sure what is the common term used here). It isn't *really* the representation of the graph. The ordering `(1,2,3,4)` can be legal for many graphs (think of a graph where they are all in a line with exactly 3 edges)