# Topological Ordering : Graphs

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

I had a look at a similar question about [topological ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947442/graphs-topological-ordering-explanation-required) but was still unsure about the concept.

There is this questions that I am unsure about.

```
Assuming the DFS visits adjacent nodes in alphabetical order, nd a topological order of
the nodes v 2 V by running the DFS on this DAG G from the source (zero in-degree)
node.
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPRoP.jpg)

For the following I got a topological order of (a, d, c, e, b, f). Would this be the correct topological ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the there can be multiple `correct` orderings for a topological sort and the one you have is correct. The thing to bear in mind is that `for every directed edge uv from vertex u to vertex v, u comes before v in the ordering` so in your graph, consider the edge a->c (a must come before c) c->e (c must come before e) e->f (e must come before f) and so on.

Comment: So according to what the question is asking (indented question), my answer would be a correct answer?